# ReactJS Google Indexation / Crawling

Tags: seo, web-crawler, reactjs, google-crawlers

I am new to ReactJS.

I have a website with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My react page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="deps.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

How to make my React app google friendly. So that google can crawl data in my website.

Comment: Anything loaded dynamically by React will not be google friendly unless you do some custom crawling/serving static content, use a service like [Seo4Ajax](http://www.seo4ajax.com/), or use [server-side rendering](http://reactjs.net/guides/server-side-rendering.html).

Comment: For anyone coming across this comment now… @YPCrumble's comment, whist probably correct at the time, is no longer correct, as Google can now index JS framework pages.  You can use the Google search console to preview what Google see, as explained here… https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en